# Jenkins pipeline throwing error. "open ./dockerignore permission denied

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I am running jenkins instance on AWS - ubuntu. 
As a part of the build process, I need to create docker image. while pipeline sh script is running command `docker build -t ${dockerImageName} ./` it throws error with open permission denied.

I have verified that user is `jenkins` and file permission for .dockerignore is `-rw-r--r--`

Comment: Can you please say what is wrong in this question before marking that as negative?

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because it does not specify one byte of the actual error message, nor does it contain one byte of your pipeline script, or any context that would enable anyone to actually help you. Thus, it is a bad question. Perhaps reading over the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and paying **especially** close attention to the [MCVE section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help you

Comment: It has details require and this is the exact error I was getting. Anyways, I have found a solution to that. I will post it in answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have find that docker command was not having enough permissions to execute this command. Then I found that it happen when we install docker using snap. I uninstalled it and then install it using apt-get. 
Then in Jenkin pipeline , I updated my $PATH variable to give location of my docker command. And it worked like a charm.